# Can't solve problem "Page not found (404)" in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have this problem and can not fix it.

`project = test_dummy`
`app = database`
This is the error message that I get:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/templates/htmlcode/homeAntragsteller.html
Using the URLconf defined in test_dummy.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='login']
[name='index_antragsteller']
The current path, templates/htmlcode/homeAntragsteller.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

database/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('', views.index_antragsteller, name='index_antragsteller'),
]
```

test_dummy/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("database.urls")),
]
```

my views.py

```
    for user_data in example_users:
        User.objects.get_or_create(email=user_data['email'],
                                   password=user_data['password'],
                                   telefonnummer=user_data['telefonummer'],
                                   vorname=user_data['vorname'],
                                   ist_bearbeiter=user_data['ist_bearbeiter'],
                                   name=user_data['name'],
                                   abteilung=user_data['abteilung'])


def user_login(request):
    create_example_users()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['passwort']
            if User.objects.filter(email=username).exists():
                user_eintrag = User.objects.get(email=username)
                if user_eintrag.password == password:
                    print("Passwort correct")
                    if user_eintrag.ist_bearbeiter:
                        return redirect('../templates/htmlcode/homeBearbeiter.html')
                    else:
                        return redirect('templates/htmlcode/homeAntragsteller.html')
                else:
                    if user_eintrag.password != password:
                        return redirect('../templates/htmlcode/login.html')
            else:
                return redirect('../templates/htmlcode/error.html')
        else:
    return render(request, '../templates/htmlcode/login.html')


@login_required
def index_antragsteller(request):
    return render(request, '../templates/htmlcode/homeAntragsteller.html')
```

in the view, I also tried to remove `../` from `../templates/htmlcode/homeAntragsteller.html` but it doesn't look like it's having any effect.

my folder structure

```
.
├───database
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───views.py
│   └───urls.py
├───test_dummy
│   ├───static
│   │   └───filesCSS
│   ├───templates
│   │   ├───bilder
│   │   ├───htmlcode
│   |   |   └───homeAntragsteller.html
│   │   └───scripts
│   ├───urls.py
│   └───__pycache__
```

I don´t understand, what cause this problem. I know, there are already questions about this problem, but I tried the solutions that were recommended. Nothing fixed my problem and I am sitting here for hours. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see two issues: a) you map two views to the same path '' (login and index_antragsteller), make sure you map each view to a dedicated url. b) you try to access pages directly from the template folder which is not supposed to work. With Django you only expose views, not their templates directly.

Comment: Also you are not using default Django project folder structure. Consider walking through [one of the basic Django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/) and begin with `startproject` and `startapp`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin to be honest, I tried to use the default project folder structure. But this also didn't worked for me and I did exactly the same, like in the tutorial. I was not able to run the server and I got the message "could not find manage.py". I was sitting there for hours, tried to fix this. I also created new projects and downloaded an other IDE, but the problem was everytime the same.

Comment: Consider asking another question with IDE+runserver+manage.py problem, provide enough details so others could understand the situation.